# Create volatile table and query against it in one request (using teradata sql assistant)

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Is it possible to construct a volatile table and query against that table in a single request while using Teradata SQL assistant?

Doing something like:

```
create volatile table table_a as 
(select .....
)
with data on commit preserve rows;

 ;select * from table_a;
```

I receive the error:

```
 Query Failed. 3932:  Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.
```

Comment: You either run both using `F9` or you connected an ANSI session. To fix the former use `F5`, to fix the latter add `COMMIT;` and use `F5`.

Comment: Thank you. I always default to f9. I did not realize there was a difference between f5 and f9...

Comment: `F5`: execute serial, `F9`: execute parallel